# Angular Error: Dependency array must have arguments

Tags: angular

I have encounter this error when I am changing a dialog form. I no longer want to use a dialog form instead ill be using form. Now when i remove @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) from the constructor i am receiving the error. Any idea?

## Constructor

```
constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: any,
    private fb:FormBuilder,
    private personService:VehicleService,
    public snack: MatSnackBar,
    private route : ActivatedRoute
) {}
```

Comment: If you remove the inject, you also have to remove the data property.

Comment: why ? what causes that one sir ?

Comment: Making an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses weak maps and injection tokens for its dependency injection.

If you remove the `@Inject`, you are left with

```
public data: any
```

Given that a weak map relies on classes, and injection tokens on provided strings, Angular becomes unable to find your data property.

This means you have to remove both lines

```
constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder,
    private personService:VehicleService,
    public snack: MatSnackBar,
    private route : ActivatedRoute
) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

bootstrapModule is not able to load/find one of the dependency defined in `AppComponent.ts` and that's why you have this error.

Incase you are struggling to find the missing dependency,

> following are steps to find out missing dependency ( verified on **Angular v8.2.3** ):

- **Navigate to function `convertInjectableProviderToFactory` in core.js**
- Put debugger in last line (last else loop) of this function:

> return function () { return new (**type**.bind.apply(type, __spread([void
> 0], injectArgs(**deps_3**))))(); };

- **type** - variable shows the name of class where the issue is
- **deps_3** - shows actual dependencies , where one of them are not being evaluated correctly.
- **Example :**

> 

```
> export class LoggerService implements Logger {  
>  
>   constructor(private apmService: **ApmService**,
>               private utilService: UtilService) {
>        }
```

If above is faulty class.

- type - will show name of class ie. LoggerService
- deps_3 - will show list of all dependencies, where if its not found then array will
  be empty ie. It could not evaluate actual dependency